# Tensorflow (v1.12.0) - what is the difference between keras.backend.clear_session() and tf.keras.backend.clear_session()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Using TensorFlow (version 1.12.0) and Keras (version 2.2.4) on a GPU cluster, I trained 10 simple and identical classifiers in a loop. I encountered unexpectedly wide variation in performance. After some troubleshooting, I decided to look into the way I was clearing the Keras session between models. I found that

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K

from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Lambda, Dense, Flatten

for i in range(10):
    K.clear_session()
    # train models
```

did not solve my problem. When I switched to

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K

from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Lambda, Dense, Flatten

for i in range(10):
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    # train models
```

the problem went away. All of my models are built on objects from `keras`, so I would have thought that having `keras` clear the session would work, but evidently it didn't.

What is the difference between `K.clear_session()` and `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` in this case? Why did the first not seem to have much effect, while the second brought my classifiers closer to their expected performance?

Comment: Maybe the root reason is because the version of keras is different in TF V1.12.0 then Keras V2.2.4

Comment: Some helpful information about `keras` vs `tf.keras` can be found[here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/21/keras-vs-tf-keras-whats-the-difference-in-tensorflow-2-0/). I don't know exactly how you are mixing the two packages,but it maybe because of some dependencies of functions.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `TF v1.12` was released on Nov 5, 2018 whereas `Keras v2.2.4` was released on Oct 03, 2018  which means `Keras v2.2.4` uses `TF v1.11` as backend.

Take a look at Tensorflow release history [here](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#history) and the Keras release history [here](https://pypi.org/project/keras/#history).